runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env:ext_statement_store_submit_statement_version_1'
I'm using polkadot-sdk-solochain-template with customization. Now, I'm trying to run the node with cargo run --release -- --dev and got this:

So, the main problem is Service(Client(VersionInvalid("Other error happened while constructing the runtime: runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env:ext_statement_store_submit_statement_version_1'")))
It's hard to understand where this error comes from.

From the log I guess you missing the HostFunction.
For example,

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/5abdc5c34c544aaf21d98778eae31ccc2349c422/templates/minimal/node/src/service.rs#L32C6-L36


Right, I've used something like sp_io::SubstrateHost.
Changed to custom HostFunction and finally it works.
Thanks!
